# Correctly extend a tkinter widget using inheritance

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

Im kinda new to python classes and I dont know how to handle them well yet, and I promise I've done some research to solve this problem but still cant figure out how to. So, here it goes:

I'm trying to use python classes to define tkinter widgets so I can implement them rather quickly. It all worked well with buttons and labels but with I cant get it with entries. I'll show you how I've coded buttons and labels to illustrate what im trying to do with entries as well (and maybe you guys can help me improve this if necessary?).

```
class buttonStatic:
    def __init__(self, parent, row, col,rowspan, text, font, bg, fg, bd,width=None, function=None,sticky=None):
        button = tk.Button(parent, text=text, font=(font), bg=bg, fg=fg,bd=bd, width=width, command=function)
        button.grid(row=row, column=col,rowspan=rowspan, padx=padx, pady=pady, sticky=sticky)

class buttonDinamic:
    def __init__(self, parent, row, col,rowspan, textVar, font, bg, fg,bd,width=None, function=None,sticky=None):
        variable = tk.StringVar()
        variable.set(textVar)
        button = tk.Button(parent, textvariable=variable, font=(font), bg=bg, fg=fg,bd=bd, width=width, command=function)
        button.grid(row=row, column=col,rowspan=rowspan, padx=padx, pady=pady, sticky=sticky)


class labelStatic:
    def __init__(self, parent, row, col, text, font, bg, fg, sticky=None):
        label = tk.Label(parent, text=text, font=(font), bg=bg, fg=fg)
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=padx, pady=pady, sticky=sticky)


class labelDinamic:
    def __init__(self, parent, row, col, textVar, font, bg, fg, sticky=None):
        variable = tk.StringVar()
        variable.set(textVar)
        label = tk.Label(parent, textvariable=variable, font=(font), bg=bg, fg=fg)
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=padx, pady=pady, sticky=sticky)
```

Now, this is what I've coded for the entries, following the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781651/showing-a-greyed-out-default-text-in-a-tk-entry) (I've added some lambda functions to make it "reusable")

```
def focusIn(entry):
    entry.delete(0,'end')
    entry.config(fg=fColor_1)
    return

def focusOut(entry):
    entry.delete(0,'end')
    entry.config(fg=fColor_3)
    entry.insert(0,'Presupuesto')
    return

def enter(entry):
    x = entry.get()
    print(entry.get())
    focusOut(entry)
    return

testEntry = tk.Entry(module,bg=bgColor_1,width = 30, fg='grey')
testEntry.grid(row=0,column = 1)
testEntry.insert(0,'Presupuesto')
testEntry.bind('<FocusIn>',lambda x: focusIn(testEntry))
testEntry.bind('<FocusOut>',lambda x: focusIn(testEntry))
testEntry.bind('<Return>',lambda x: enter(testEntry))
```

Here is my actual question

*How to make into a class and, how to use the `.get()` and `.set()` methods when the widget is made into a class?*

As im not very experienced in python classes (and especially combining them with tkinter) I dont even know if what I'm asking is possible!
p.d.: Sorry if my english is not very good, it's not my native language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: How to make into a own `class` from a `tkinter.Entry`

It's called inheritance.
All. inherited methods, e.g. `.get()` behave the same.

```
class MyEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        # Defaults
        kwargs['fg'] = 'grey'
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_event)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_event)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.on_event)

    def on_event(self, event):
        print('on_event type:{}'.format(event.type))
```

> **Usage**:

```
testEntry = MyEntry(module, bg=bgColor_1, width = 30)
testEntry.grid(row=0,column = 1)
testEntry.insert(0,'Presupuesto')

print(testEntry.get())
```

Comment: thanks! with a little digging about inheritance I got it working!