# how can i have the function to enable / disable the entries near the buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.buttons = []
        self.entries = []

        for n_row in range(20):
            button = tk.Button(self, text='disable')
            button.grid(row=n_row, column=1)
            entry = tk.Entry(self)
            entry.grid(row=n_row, column=0, pady=(10,10))
            self.entries.append(entry)
            self.buttons.append(button)
#each button must activate / deactivate the entry of the same row

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use lambda here to keep the correct index value for each of the entry fields.

You can use the value of `n_row` to keep track of what button links to what entry.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.entries = []
        for n_row in range(20):
            self.entries.append(tk.Entry(self))
            self.entries[-1].grid(row=n_row, column=0, pady=(10,10))
            tk.Button(self, text='disable', command=lambda i=n_row: self.disable_entry(i)).grid(row=n_row, column=1)

    def disable_entry(self, ndex):
        self.entries[ndex]['state'] = 'disabled'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

For switching between both states you can use the same method to check if the state is one thing and then change it to another.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.entries = []
        self.buttons = []
        for n_row in range(20):
            self.entries.append(tk.Entry(self))
            self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self, text='disable', command=lambda i=n_row: self.toggle_state(i)))
            self.entries[-1].grid(row=n_row, column=0, pady=(10, 10))
            self.buttons[-1].grid(row=n_row, column=1)

    def toggle_state(self, ndex):
        if self.entries[ndex]['state'] == 'normal':
            self.entries[ndex]['state'] = 'disabled'
            self.buttons[ndex].config(text='Enable')
        else:
            self.entries[ndex]['state'] = 'normal'
            self.buttons[ndex].config(text='Disable')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: A `Button` that activate / deactivate the entry in the same Row

Define your own widget which combines `tk.Button` and `tk.Entry` in a own `tk.Frame`.
The `Entry` state get toggeld on every click on the `Button`.

[image]

---

**Relevant**
- [extend a tkinter widget using inheritance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322108/7414759)

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class ButtonEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='\u2327', width=1, command=self.on_clicked)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')

    def on_clicked(self):
        b = not self.entry['state'] == 'normal'
        state, text = {True: ('normal', '\u2327'), False: ('disabled', '\u221A')}.get(b)
        self.entry.configure(state=state)
        self.button.configure(text=text)
```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        for row in range(5):
            ButtonEntry(self).grid(row=row, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Answer (score -2):

You can set the `state`of a widget to `'disabled'`

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
entry = Entry(root, state = 'disabled')
```

To disable an individual item:

```
entry['state'] = 'disabled'
```

When you push the button, get it's location in the list, than compare that to the entry in the other list. If they match, change its state.

Comment: def block():
    if entry['state'] == 'normal':
        entry['state'] = 'disabled'
    elif entry['state'] =='disabled':
        entry['state'] = 'normal'

Comment: Writing a different function for each button is not the correct way to do this.