# Set Entry value from a browse button in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-class

i'm not very good in Python especially when using classes. I write this code to set the Entry value using a browse button, the problem is that in this way i should create a browse method for each button. There is a easier way to solve this problem?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        self.button1 = Button(text = 'browse', command = self.browse1)     
        self.button1.grid (row = 0, column = 1)

        self.input_file1 = Entry(textvariable = self.browse1)
        self.input_file1.grid(row=0, column = 0)

        self.button2 = Button(text = 'browse', command = self.browse2)     
        self.button2.grid (row = 1, column = 1)

        self.input_file2 = Entry(textvariable = self.browse2)
        self.input_file2.grid(row=1, column = 0)

    def browse1(self):
        filename = askopenfilename(title = 'Select a file')
        self.input_file1.delete(0, END)
        self.input_file1.insert(0, filename)

    def browse2(self):
        filename = askopenfilename(title = 'Select a file')
        self.input_file2.delete(0, END)
        self.input_file2.insert(0, filename)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x550')
root.title('prove') 
MyApp = App(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Follow this approach [extend a tkinter widget using inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60536050/7414759)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your function as this:

```
def browse(self, entry):
    filename = askopenfilename(title = 'Select a file')
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(0, filename)
```

and then change your definitions to this:

```
self.button1 = Button(text = 'browse', command = lambda: self.browse(self.input_file1))     
self.button1.grid (row = 0, column = 1)

self.input_file1 = Entry()
self.input_file1.grid(row=0, column = 0)
```

Then when the button is pressed, it calls the `lambda` function which calls the `browse()` function, passing the corresponding entry field to the function which can then insert the text.

Hope this makes sense, let me know if you have any problems :)

Comment: Great!! thank you now it works i was sure that it wouldn't be difficult!