# How properly use our code in different tabs using the classes?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

I want to create different tabs in my GUI, and be able to write different codes in each tab, and also be able to transfer the variables between tabs. So I tried to write it in different classes. But my code cannot show the defined labels in the proper tab. I want to show `label1` in class `tab1`, `label2` in class `tab2`, and so on.
here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = tk.IntVar()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(400, 400)
        self.maxsize(400, 400)

        my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        my_notebook.pack()

        tab_frame1 = tk.Frame(my_notebook, width=400, height=400)
        tab_frame1.pack()

        tab_frame2 = tk.Frame(my_notebook, width=400, height=400)
        tab_frame2.pack()

        tab_frame3 = tk.Frame(my_notebook, width=400, height=400)
        tab_frame3.pack()

        my_notebook.add(tab_frame1, text="Tab1")
        my_notebook.add(tab_frame2, text="Tab2")
        my_notebook.add(tab_frame3, text="Tab3")
        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (tab1, tab2, tab3):
            frame1 = F(tab_frame1, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame1
            frame1.pack()


class tab1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab1")
        label1.pack()


class tab2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab2")
        label2.pack()


class tab3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab3")
        label3.pack()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848270/python-tkinter-tab-classes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032712/ttk-notebook-share-data-between-imported-tabs) for using notebook in classes. In your example you have `frame1=F(tab_frame1, self.data)` which only sets up `tab_frame1` for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = tk.IntVar()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(400, 400)
        self.maxsize(400, 400)

        self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.my_notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.app_data = {}

        lst = [tab1, tab2, tab3]
        for N, F in enumerate(lst):
            tab = F(self.my_notebook, self.app_data)
            self.my_notebook.add(tab, text="Tab"+str(N+1))

        self.data = Data()


class tab1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab1")
        label1.pack()


class tab2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab2")
        label2.pack()


class tab3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab3")
        label3.pack()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```