# How do I add a placeholder for a tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

[image]

How do i make a placeholder for a tkinter Entry widget like in the google search bar shown above?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781651/showing-a-greyed-out-default-text-in-a-tk-entry) might be relevant.

Comment: The proper term for this is *placeholder text* - you can find examples by searching for that.

Comment: @jasonharper yeah that's what I meant, just didn't know the right word

Comment: @Pankaj i guess i could do that but I'm looking for a shorter way of doing that